# Jacoco classdumpdir option cannot include all loaded class files shown in sessions.html

Tags: gradle, jacoco

According to http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html, all loaded class files during execution will be dumped into classdumpdir.

However, after I configured "-javaagent:/home/d/test11/jacoco-example/lib/jacocoagent.jar=classdumpdir=/home/d/test11/jacoco-example/dump" as the JVM options, in classdumpdir I could only see about 15% of the class files shown in sessions.html of my report. This means most of the loaded class files are not dumped.

Has anyone else ever used this option? Are you able to get all the class files? What am I doing wrong? Is it possible it is because I have multiple subprojects under the main projects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a maven project, you may want to try using this property

```
<jacoco.classDumpDir>${project.build.directory}/classdumps</jacoco.classDumpDir>
```